# Saving Google search queries and getting it right

Tags: php

When building a web application I needed to save referrer Google search queries to a file and later on echo them.

The thing I have tried so far is:

```
function write_to_file($q)
{$filename = 'sitemap.dat';
$fh = fopen($filename, "a");
if(flock($fh, LOCK_EX))
{fwrite($fh, $q);
flock($fh, LOCK_UN);}
fclose($fh);}

$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(strstr($ref, "http://")){
if(strstr($ref, "google.com")){
  //echo $ref;  
  $regex ='/q=(.+?)&/';
  preg_match($regex, $ref, $query);
    $user_query = ''.$query[1].'';

write_to_file($user_query);
 }}
```

Simplifying the above code first it creates a function to save text into file, then it looks for a refer, checks if it is not `https` then it check if it's google.com.

All sorted now it grabs the query part and writes it to the file. However I can't get it working because the page after the script is not displayed and nothing is saved in sitemap.dat.

Also, if I remove the file function it echos `search%20query`, which is I want.

Comment: I am not getting why are you skipping "https://" URLs? There are too rare cases(many be no case) in which google will refer to any site with "http://" connection.

Comment: Because https won't give full reference url's, for the sake of privacy of users signed in. That's why https is there.
And they refer with http if user is not signed in and/or has a old mobile phone.
Clearing more I don't have a https on my website.

Comment: can you paste any such reference URL here?

Comment: yes http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=char%20din%20ki%20zindagi%20pyar%20kiye%20bin%20mubi%20all%20video%20song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.

```
function write_to_file($q=''){
    if($q==='') return false;
    $fh = fopen('sitemap.dat', "a");
    if(flock($fh, LOCK_EX)){
        fwrite($fh, $q."\n");
        flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
    }
    fclose($fh);
    echo 'done';
}

$ref = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

if(strstr($ref, "http://www.google.co")){
    preg_match('/q=(.+)&?/', $ref, $query);
    if(count($query)>1){
        write_to_file($query[1]);
    }
}
```